# Telerik Kendo Grid Parameter Map Validate Data

Tags: parameters, kendo-ui, return, kendo-grid

I am trying to validate the data to be sent on server using parameter map function in Telerik Kendo Grid. But i am unable to avoid server request if in valid data.

I have tries return false. Which is sending null to the server request. I want to avoid server request if data is not valid.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.preventDefault() if it's invalid. If it's not working then please share your code